# Can't use a chart module with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am new to use angular.js.

I want to use gauge module ,but after i finish my html following  [Angular Gauge Document](https://ashish-chopra.github.io/angular-gauge/#/getting-started),it's not working(browser shows nothing).
I guess the problem is i didnt make the module work.
Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<ng-gauge size="150" type="full" thick="5" 
      min="0" max="120" value="68.2" 
      cap="round" label="Speed" append="mph"
      foreground-color="#ffcc66" background-color="#EEE">
</ng-gauge>
</body>

<script src="http://cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-gauge/dist/angularjs-gauge.min.js"></script>

<script>

angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-gauge']);

</script>
</html>
```

Plus, in the document installation part,it says:

> As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the chart.js module:

i didnt use chart.js module in my project,so which **chart.js** file this guide refer to ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the script tags inside the body tag, also you included the angular.min.js twice.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<ng-gauge size="150" type="full" thick="5" 
      min="0" max="120" value="68.2" 
      cap="round" label="Speed" append="mph"
      foreground-color="#ffcc66" background-color="#EEE">
</ng-gauge>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ashish-chopra/angular-gauge/master/src/angularjs-gauge.js"></script>

<script>

angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-gauge']);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```